# Graph of $f([x])$ according to $f$

Tags: functions

If the graph of function $f$ on $[-1,2)$ is the following graph, what's the graph of $y=f([x])$ on the same interval?

[image]

What I've tried:

I thought on $[0,2]$ it was a horizontal line like the constant function $f=1$ and on $[-1,0]$ it'd be the same with $f=-1$ but it's wrong.

Comment: @lhf I edited my question, hope it's enough now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $g(x)=f([x])$. Then $g(x)=f(-1)$ in $[-1,0)$, $g(x)=f(0)$ in $[0,1)$, $g(x)=f(1)$ in $[1,2)$ and $g(2)=f(2)$.

Comment: I realized where I made a mistake, thanks.